# I Get An Error When I Use mapbax-gl.css with react/typescript

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, webpack, mapbox-gl-js

When i built a map with mapbox-gl by using react/typescript, i got an error where i imported css file for the mapbox-gl "import 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css';"

i cant figure out what kind of loader do i still need cuz in "webpack.config.js" ive already imported css-loader....

error

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

webpack.config.js

````
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

module.exports = () => {
  const env = dotenv.config().parsed;

  const envKeys = Object.keys(env).reduce((prev, next) => {
    prev[`process.env.${next}`] = JSON.stringify(env[next]);
    return prev;
  }, {});

  return {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/index.tsx'),
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: [
            'style-loader',
            'css-loader',
            'postcss-loader',
            'sass-loader'
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.tsx?$/,
          use: 'ts-loader',
          exclude: /node_modules/,
        },
      ],
    },
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './public/index.html'
      }),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin(envKeys)
    ],
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js', '.json']
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    output: {
      filename: 'bundle.js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    devServer: {
      contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
      historyApiFallback: true,
      inline: true,
      hot: true,
      port: 5000,
      open: true
    },
  }
};
```
````

Answer (score 0):

You didn't match the `css-loader` on the correct extension.

Use it against `.css` files instead, by adding a new rule :

```
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: [
        'css-loader',
      ]
    },
    {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        'postcss-loader',
        'sass-loader'
      ]
    },
```